# WIX - Reload Page if URL Changes

Tags: javascript, velo

I want to force Wix to refresh if the URL changes ever. Wix loads pages internally via some sort of Ajax, however as a result some tracking cookies don't capture the navigation changes correctly. Refreshing the page if a URL change happens provides a fix for this but I need to automate it,

Alternatively, reload the tracking code when this URL change occurs.

Regards

Henry

Answer (score 0):

This might work: Use the [`wix-location.onChange()`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-location/onchange) function to listen for URL changes and then use the [`wix-location.to()`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-location/to) function to reload the page.

So, something like this:

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';

$w.onReady(() => {
    wixLocation.onChange(location => {
       wixLocation.to(location.path);
    });
});
```

Comment: so I'm adding this to Wix, however it doesn't appear to be refreshing the page on page load. I tried adding console.log(wixLocation); however nothing is being logged in console either